# Is there a way to create log compacted topic using kafka-python library?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

kafka-python contains multiple modules to create/delete topic and also pass multiple configuration while doing so.

Is there a way to add additional configuration to following method -

`NewTopic(name=topicname, num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible to create a compacted topic with kafka-python.

The [`NewTopic`](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/admin/new_topic.py) constructor accepts a `topic_configs` argument to specify the topic configurations.

For example:

```
from kafka import KafkaAdminClient
from kafka.admin import NewTopic

admin = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
topic = NewTopic('bar', 1, 1, topic_configs={'cleanup.policy': 'compact'})
response = admin.create_topics([topic])

print(response)
```